# How do differential 2-forms give us bilinear forms on tangent spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology, differential-forms

Suppose $\omega$ is a 2-form on a manifold $M$. So, by definition,  $\omega$ is a section $M \to \bigwedge^2 T^*M$ where $\bigwedge^2 T^* M :=\sum_{p \in M} \bigwedge^2 (T_pM)^*$.

It seems to be a commonly used fact that $\omega$ can be interpreted as a bilinear form $\omega : T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb R$ on each tangent space. I know this is because there is an isomorphism $\bigwedge^2 V^* \to (\bigwedge^2 V)^*$ for any vector space $V$. I've seen several sources refer to this isomorphism as "natural," which usually means we don't need to chose a basis to construct it.

So how do we construct this isomorphism? Any other explantions/intuition are welcome.

Comment: I suggest $\bigwedge^2 V^*\rightarrow (\bigwedge^2 V)^*$, mapping $\xi\wedge \eta$ to the linear form $v\wedge w\mapsto \frac12\cdot \bigl(\xi(v)\cdot \eta(w) - \xi(w)\cdot\eta(v)\bigr)$. One needs to check well-definedness and bijectivity (I haven't done it). But at least, this does not depend on any choice of basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The wedge-product $\wedge$ is the anti-symmetric subspace of the tensor-product $\otimes$. I.e. for any two vector spaces $V,W$, the wedge product $V\wedge W$ is a subspace of $V\otimes W$. and for vectors $v\in V, w\in W$ one can define
   $$v\wedge w = v\otimes w - w\otimes v$$
   (though there might be a factor of $1/2$ depending on your literature. Thanks @Ted-Shifrin)
2. There is an isomorphism between $(V\otimes W)^*$ and $V^*\otimes W^*$, which you can simply write as $$(\alpha\otimes\beta)(v\otimes w)=\alpha(v)\cdot \beta(w)$$ and extending by linearity, where "$\cdot$" is just multiplication of real/complex numbers.
3. writing this down for the wedge-product case becomes $$(\alpha\wedge\beta)(v\otimes w)=\alpha(v)\beta(w)-\beta(v)\alpha(w)$$
   which you can also write as $(\alpha\otimes\beta)(v,w)$

Comment: Just a side comment. With the factor of $1/2$, the unit square has area $1/2$. I detest that.

Comment: Actually, I did seom rethinking, and think you are right, the factor $1/2$ should not be there. Without it, the $n$-th wedge-product gives the determinant as it should be. I'm still a little confused what I was thinking, but for now changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, Simon, you're right that there are different conventions, and there are numerous textbooks (including Kobayashi-Nomizu and Guillemin-Pollack) which — in order to "simplify" the definitions — have unit cubes with volume $1/n!$. Ugh. :) Warner many, many years ago wrote a footnote clarifying the fact that, for example, the DeRham Theorem does not depend on which convention you use.

Comment: I did check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_multilinear_forms which does not use 1/n! but defines a separate function "Alt", which does. Anyway, lets keep it like this here. I doubt it is important for the sake of this question^^.